# mySQL search across multiple rows return distinct id

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm having trouble searching across a sub-table.  Here is a simple example:

table: project_details

[image: data]

I would like to search a project by its name, description and then correlate it with project_list_id for example zip and state.

I know the problem is with how I am searching the detailed table.  So I have broke it down to something simpler with just one table:

```
SELECT `ProjectDetail`.`project_list_id` FROM `database`.`project_details` AS `ProjectDetail` WHERE (
    (
        (
            (`ProjectDetail`.`answer` = '96720') 
            AND 
            (`ProjectDetail`.`field_name` = 'zip')
        )
    ) 
    AND (
        (
            (`ProjectDetail`.`answer` = 'HI') 
            AND 
            (`ProjectDetail`.`field_name` = 'state')
        )
    ) 
)
```

I want to select the project_list_id that meets both of these field requirements, but since they are unique rows, nothing gets returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you wan't to return all projects_ids which separately for every id meet both condition. So this should work:

```
SELECT a.project_list_id 
FROM database.project_details a
INNER JOIN database.project_details b
ON a.project_list_id = b.project_list_id
WHERE a.answer = '96720' AND a.field_name = 'zip'
AND b.answer = 'HI' AND b.field_name = 'state'
```

Comment: Distinct was left in by accident.  I want to find the project_list_id that is true for BOTH cases at the same time.  If you look at the data you'll see the case is project_list_id=1 where both conditions would be met.

Comment: Perhaps the way to do this is with two selects and a UNION but it seems like there should be a way to do this.

Comment: Similiar values in answer column mislead me. So then distinct with be necessary. But also OR is necesary. I'll edit my answer

Comment: The problem with using OR is that it doesn't require both HI and 96720 to be true.  So if another set of project_list_id has just HI or just 96720 then it will also be selected.

Comment: I misunderstood you firstly. I hope after editing my answer will be correct

Comment: I appreciate the help.  It has taken me a while to verify this works and it does.  Can you explain it a little more because I have to expand this into a much more complicated query?

Comment: If you 'join' tables columns of both tables 'concatenate' to create single row. So the row will looks that way: 2 | 1 | state | HI | 3 | 1 | zip | 96720. First columns are from table which was given alias 'a'. Next there are columns from table which was given alias 'b'. Then you apply all 4 conditions to state, HI from a and zip, 96720 from b. Join was on a.project_list_id = b.project_list_id so every rows which has the same project_list_id from tables was concatenated (every combination)